# Remove enclosing brackets from a string in C#

Tags: c#, brackets

I need to remove enclosing brackets from a string in C# in [code-behind](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/code-behind).

For example, if I have a string as `[My [] Groups]`, I want to turn it into `My [] Groups`.

Comment: take a look at string.replace()

Comment: add String.Replace() as new tool to your toolbox?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The simplest way of addressing this using the string from your example would be taking a substring:

```
if (s.Length > 2) {
    s = s.Substring(1, s.Length-2);
}
```

This works only when you are 100% certain that the first and the last characters are indeed square brackets. If they are not, for example, when the string is untrimmed, you may need to perform additional string manipulations (e.g. trimming the string).

Comment: This implies that the '[' and the ']' is ONLY located at the beginning and end of the string. This could very well be the case for the user but it's not stated in the question.

Comment: @inquam I absolutely agree that the question is somewhat under-defined. The substring trick works for the example from the post, but it might not work if the requirements are more complicated than that.

Comment: @Neon Just remember that if you run this on a string that is NOT enclosed within brackets it will still remove the first and last character of that string.

Answer (score 20):

Try this:

```
yourString = yourString.Replace("[", string.Empty).Replace("]", string.Empty);
```

[Updated answer](https://dotnetfiddle.net/dF4lyC) since the question was edited:

```
string s = "[My [] Groups]";
string pattern = @"^(\[){1}(.*?)(\]){1}$";
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(s, pattern, "$2")); // will print My [] Groups
```

Answer (score 15):

Simple to use `Trim`:

```
var result = "[My [] Groups]".Trim('[', ']');
```

Answer (score 7):

Check out the `String.Replace` method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.asp

*Update:*

If only enclosing brackets are to be removed you can just strip away the first and last char. Either by the code suggested by dasblinkenlight or by a regular expression.

**Just make sure that they are indeed brackets first.**

If you use a regular expression you can do all of this in one go. Otherwise you should add something like this to dasblinkenlight's solution.

```
if (s.Length > 2) {
  if(s.StartsWith("[")) {
    s = s.Substring(1, s.Length-1);
  }
  if(s.EndsWith("]")) {
    s = s.Substring(0, s.Length-1);
  }
}
```

or if you only wish to strip if you have both a *starting* and a *closing* bracket

```
if (s.Length > 2) {
  if(s.StartsWith("[") && s.EndsWith("]")) {
    s = s.Substring(1, s.Length-2);
  }
}
```

The check for if the length is greater than 2 can probably be removed to, but I kept it in to show that the source of the initial code was the one written by dasblinkenlight.

Comment: Who or what is "dasblinkenlight"?

Comment: Seems like that user probably changed name (or deleted their answer) in the past 10 years ;)

Answer (score 3):

The following statement removes all characters [ and ].

```
Regex.Replace("This [is [a] [test.", @"[\[\]]", "")   // -> "This is a test."
```

Answer (score 3):

The Replace solutions will get rid of the internal brackets as well as the external ones.  I think you want:

```
string result = "[My [] Groups]".TrimLeft('[').TrimRight(']');
```

Comment: In C# its TrimStart and TrimEnd

Answer (score 1):

```
var myString = "[My Groups]";
myString.Replace("[", string.Empty);
myString.Replace("]", string.Empty);
```

Comment: @Artem Vyshniakov... thanks for reply. if suppose my string is like this [My [] Groups]. In this case what i should do to replace the starting '[' and ending ']'. so that my result is My [] Groups. thanks

Comment: I doubt if @Neon is testing the code.

Comment: @Neon: IF you want '[My [] Groups]' to turn into 'My [] Groups' you just have to strip the first and last char. Try to be more clear in your question if you want to remove enclosing brackets or ALL brackets from your string.

Answer (score 1):

Try `string.Replace`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx